# webpack watch only watching entry

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a project setup using webpack 1.13.0 and it seems that when using `webpack --watch` it will only watch for changes in the entry point file.

I have a project structure where I have js files in `$root\src` folder and the entry point file is `main.js` with the following:

```
import * as strings from 'strings'
document.write(strings.sayHello('foobar'));
```

And strings is in the same folder with this

```
export const helloWorld = 'Hello, world!';

export function sayHello(name) {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
}

export const foo = 'bar';
export const bar = 'foo';
```

webpack.config.js contains this

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.js",
    output: {filename: "./dist/bundle.js"},

    resolve: {root: __dirname + '/src'},

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
              presets: ['es2015']
          }
        }
      ]
    }
};
```

Now if I make any changes to `main.js` it will recompile but changes to `strings.js` will not trigger a recompile.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `resolve.root` configuration option? I have a feeling that's the culprit and it doesn't look quite necessary in this case.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the same thing right now :(

Comment: I am facing similar issue :(

Comment: same issue on  "webpack": "3.5.1" for a `node` target

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with webpack 3

how I fixed it was in my webpack config I changed all concatenated pathnames that used `__dirname` to use `path.resolve`

so in your example `resolve: {root: __dirname + '/src'},` should be:
`resolve: root: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src')`

Additionally I found I had a file system case sensitivity issue. my file system had an upper case directory name `/Network/index.js` my code was importing `/network/index.js`. Webpack was able to resolve this path on the initial run but it didn't register it on the watch cycles. I lowercased the directory name and it started working.

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be the import statement:

```
import * as strings from 'strings'
```

If my understanding is correct, webpack (by default) looks inside `node_modules` for any aliased folders when importing from a non-relative path. This may fix your issue (change `'strings'` to `'./strings`):

```
import * as strings from './strings';
```